# Toggle Two Divs Onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a function that toggles two divs onclick. I have 2 functions that displays an api json data as a table and graph (`formatGraph` and `formatTable`).
i have created two different divs and appended the `formatGraph` and `formatTable` functions to those divs. Then created a `mainDiv` to wrap the two divs.

I have an if statement that checks for when to show or hide the divs. I am calling the `formatData` function somewhere in my fetch call while rendering my result. I have a css file with the following code:

```
.displayTable {
    display: block;
}

.displayGraph{
    display: none;
}
```

But I am currently getting `undefined` and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at HTMLButtonElement.
```

Any idea what I am missing, or how I can go about this? Here's my function:

```
const formatData = (response) => {
    const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const div1= document.createElement("div");
    div1.classList.add("displayTable");
    div1.appendChild(formatTable(response));
    mainDiv.appendChild(div1)

    const div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.classList.add("displayGraph");
    div2.appendChild(formatGraph(response));
    mainDiv.appendChild(div2)
    

    viewTable.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if(document.querySelector('.displayTable').style.display === "none") {
        document.querySelector('.displayGraph').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.displayTable').style.display = 'block';
    }

    else{
        document.querySelector('.displayTable').style.display === "none"
       document.querySelector('.displayGraph').style.display = 'block';
    }
    
    
})
};
```

Comment: Your element is `undefined` and you are trying to access the `style` property on it, Probably your element is not loaded in the browser, The line no error pointing to, that is undefined, if you can console log `document.querySelector('<your-selector>')`, you will see undefined

Comment: Try adding `type="module"` to your HTML script tag so that the JS loads **after** your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code looks OK, but you're forgetting to *append* `mainDiv` to the document. That's why you're getting `null` as a result of calling `document.querySelector(".displayTable")` and `document.querySelector(".displayGraph")`. Using the access operator in `null` results in a TypeError.

```js
//...
const div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.classList.add("displayGraph");
div2.appendChild(formatGraph(response));
mainDiv.appendChild(div2)
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
//...
```

I've just used `.appendChild` in `body`, which appends the element at the end of the body. There are different methods that let you append elements at different locations of the DOM three. You could also create an empty element (has no children) in your HTML and use that element as a wrapper to append the DIVS.

Also, consider an improvement in your handler:

```js
viewTable.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Execute document.querySelector once.
  const displayTableDiv = document.querySelector('.displayTable')
  const displayGraphDiv = document.querySelector('.displayGraph')
  
  /* This new condition will prevent the Type Error if any. */
  if (displayTableDiv && displayGraphDiv) {
    if(displayTableDiv.style.display === "none") {
      displayGraphDiv.style.display = 'none';
      displayTableDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      displayTableDiv.style.display === "none"
      displayGraphDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Lucas. I added ```result.appendChild(mainDiv) to my code. The ```result``` here is the div that displays the result. I am no longer getting a blank page or error. But just the table data is displayed and my toggle button doesn't show.